# Need help in designing mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

the scenario is , person X posts some event. For that event multiple other people(200-300 people) quotes their price,,,,

now i need to store a the quoted values with information about quoted people,,,

please help me

Comment: Very subjective question, let us know what design you have decided or what is your thought on problem

Answer (score 1):

You will need the following :

```
Users table     ->  For Registered user  
Events Table    -> Registered user posts an event
Quotation Table -> Where each user/guest can post price
```

## Table Column

User Table      -> **id**, name, email, password (minimum)

Event Table     -> **event_id, user_id**, event_name, event_description,..

Quotation Table -> **Quotation_id, User_id**, Quotation_price,...

## Relationship

```
Each User can have many Events 
Each Event can have many Quotation
```